# Windows to Wine | Getting "could not load file or assembly [etc]" exception

Tags: ubuntu, wine, c#

This case involves writing a program that will eventually use Mono, but until then is using Wine as a substitute.

Currently, there is a problem with a particular reference:

> Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.dll 'version=1.0.0.0 [etc]' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference

So far, with my attempts, using Assembly Binding Redirection with this reference hasn't solved this; even changing the referenced version number to 1.0.0.0 then throws version 2.1.0.0 cannot be loaded instead.

Recompiling the program after deleting the /bin folder and updating the references using Nuget didn't solve the problem.

It does work in the native Windows environment, so this seems Wine-specific, perhaps?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is Windows specific knowledge, no matter Wine being used or not. This question is probably more suited to our sister site Superuser

Comment: Ah makes sense that using Wine doesn't necessarily qualify this here

Comment: Have you loaded wine-mono for .NET compatibility?

Comment: @fixer1234 Yes, the wine-mono package is installed in the prefix, also fyi, until I get the Mono port finished, Mono, at least by itself, doesn't work as the program uses Windows APIs (via NAudio).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Update

In this particular circumstance, using a new Wine prefix with a clean install of certain components using `winetricks` helped solved the problem.

#### Additional steps

In conjunction, before using a new prefix, as mentioned in the question, the references were updated. Also, `Assembly Binding Redirection` was already applied to the mentioned reference, so it wasn't necessary to do manually (the changes that were tested prior at the time of posting the question were reverted to default).

A last note is that `Wine-Mono` was not required, and was not added to the new Wine prefix, even to test if it was causing any errors previously (perhaps unlikely).